# Adding values in the rows of a table?

Tags: jquery, html

i have a table with 3 columns and i need to get the sum of the values in the second coloumn I am keeping an ID which is used to identify cells of addition. I need to do it in J query ?I would like to know how I can able to acess each rows and colums of a table using for loop.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>52</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can I able to access each rows using some indexes like #tbl[row][col] etc .Thnaks In Advance
I NEED TO ADD THE VALUES WHERE ID WILL BE ONE THAT IS EXPECTED OUTPUT IS 92[40+52]

Comment: The sum of the values in the second column is 40+35+52 = 127. Did you deliberately omit the second row from your addition? If so, why? And what're the `id`s or `class`es that're supposed to be added together?

Comment: @David Thomas- It's clear to me that `ID[1]:Mark[40]` and another `ID[1]:Mark[52]`, and the OP added the `Mark` to `92`, `40+52`. Well, I may be wrong.

Comment: @Reigel - Yes that was the result i need.I need to get the sum if the ID is same.

Comment: @Reigel, that would make sense, it's just that I was thrown by his statement that he '[needs] to get the sum of the values...' and then omitting one of them.

Comment: @Hari, no worries. I just misunderstood is all =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
​function getTotal(id) {
  var total = 0;
  $("td:first-child").filter(function() { return this.innerHTML == id; })
      .next().each(function() { total += parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10); });
  return total;           
}
```

For example:

```
alert(getTotal(1)); // alerts 92
alert(getTotal(2)); // alerts 35
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ngMte/1/)., what this does is get the first columns of cells, does a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) down to those that match the ID (don't use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) here, it's a substring match) then for the matches, get the neighboring cell using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).  For those cells we're just using [`praseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the number and add it to the `total`.

Comment: thanks for ur answer .But i need to change the ID in to last.How can i access the last column.Similar condition.But that column's style is set to display:none

Comment: @Hari - I'm not following, you want to update the last column of *each* of those rows with the total?

Comment: @Thanks Nick :)  I changed some code and made it works Thanks

Comment: @Hari - ah ok, just make sure you're all set :)